# Error 1281 in stbi_failure_reason() causing PNG images not to be shown

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am trying to create openGl (lwjgl) application which uses stb texture loading. Before I used my texture, I had loaded this by the stbi_load() function. My PNG (sRGB,4 channels) image aren`t shown in the window. Function stbi_failure_reason() returns "Corrupt JPEG" even I used PNG file. After binding texture segment GL11.glGetError() returns 1281 (Bad values). I have checked ByteBuffer - sometimes negative values occur. Does anyone know what is wrong?

```java
int w;
int h;
int id;

IntBuffer wx = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
IntBuffer hx = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
IntBuffer cx = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);

ByteBuffer data = stbi_load("./assets/img/gui/logo.png", wx, hx, cx, 4);

if(data == null) {
    System.out.println("Failed to load texture");
}
System.out.println(stbi_failure_reason());
System.out.println(cx.get(0));

id = GL11.glGenTextures();
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
System.out.println(GL11.glGetError());
w = wx.get();
h = hx.get();

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 4, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
stbi_image_free(data);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

Comment: Please don't include tags in the title - it's unnecessary and distracting. The title should only summarize the problem; that way can tell more easily if the post is relevant to them or if they're likely to know the answer or not.

Comment: Not related to the question but please see: [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190)

Comment: Are you sure that the error is caused by `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id)` and not before? Note, [`glGetError`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glGetError.xhtml) returns the value of the error flag and resets the error flag. But the error flag could have been set by any instruction since the last call to `glGetError`.

Comment: 1). OK. I will keep it in mind.
2). glGetError before glBindTexture() return 0 - no errors.

Comment: @RobertRadziszewski I'm a bit confused when you call `GL11.glGenTextures` then you're using the class `GL11`, but you don't when you call `glBindTexture`.

Comment: I don't know why you suspect an issue with OpenGL texture setup if the `stbi_load()` call already errors out? What do you expect GL to do in case of a not loaded image?